# Can I do a WHERE clause to filter a json_agg column in the outer query?

Tags: postgresql, json

The way that I am building this query dynamically is that everything is static that is located before the last `WHERE` clause.  The `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses can be created and appended based on what query params are sent over.

```
SELECT
  vco.id,
  vco.branch,
  (
    SELECT json_agg(x) as cars from
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM car_info
      WHERE branch = vco.branch
    ) as x
  )
FROM vendor_car_orders vco
-- added dynamically based on query params
WHERE cars->>'color' = 'blue'
AND cars->>'doors' = 4
ORDER BY 1;
```

results without any filter

[image: all results]

results wanted using `WHERE` clause in outer select with doors = 4 and color = blue

[image: filtered]

Comment: Are you trying to change what is in the generated JSON, or select rows from vendor_car_orders based on what is in the JSON? An example might help us understand what you are asking.

Comment: Note that your column doesn't have an alias. But even if it did, you can't reference a column alias from the SELECT list directly in the WHERE clause on the same level. You would need to wrap query in a derived table. But still: the JSON value will be an array, so you would need to use `where cars -> 0 ->> color = 'blue'` to check e.g. the first array element.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Do you need a variable number of conditions, or will they always be exactly two? Will they always be on `color` and `doors`?

Comment: i added my desired results, thanks!

Comment: Can you update the question and add the PostgreSQL version in use?

Comment: The correlated subquery in your original query makes sure *all* rows from `vendor_car_orders` are included, even with empty `cars`. Your added desired result contradicts that query. You should clarify what you actually want. (And always declare your version of Postgres.)

Comment: The correlated subquery that returns all rows is what I currently have.  Now I have a new requirement to allow for filtering based on other criteria.  So what I want is for someone to tell me how to change what I currently have in order to accommodate for the new requirements to dynamically filter the rows as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking out the subqueries makes the job much easier:

```
SELECT vco.id, vco.branch, json_agg(car_info) as cars -- Static
FROM car_info                                         -- Static
JOIN vendor_car_orders vco USING (branch)             -- Static
WHERE color = 'blue' AND doors = 4                    -- Conditions go here
GROUP BY vco.id, vco.branch                           -- Static
ORDER BY vco.id                                       -- Optional ordering goes here
```

Easy to compose the query in client code or as Dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL. The call to `json_agg(car_info)` is a bit of PostgreSQL magic, where a table implicitly defines a matching composite type. If there are ever columns in `car_info` that shouldn't appear in the JSON then use a view to hide them.

Comment: Pro tip: start your WHERE clause with `WHERE 1 = 1`, then you can dynamically add `And... And...` filters much more easily. Careful with OR operators, always enclose them in ( ) brackets and use 0=1 at the start instead.